# Clone Git Repo With PHP

Tags: php, git, installation, git-clone

I'm creating an installer which creates a database, user with permissions and then will pull through a website framework from an internal git repo. I've got everything pretty much working but struggling to find a way to do a git clone via php and download the files.

Any guidance or tips to do this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Google tells you what?

Comment: https://github.com/czproject/git-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume git is installed on the server you are running the code on. If so you can just run the command `git clone ...` from php using either the built-in [exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or use a 3rd party library like [Symfony's Process-component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)